# non-greedy search for redundant values in string

Tags: regex

Basically I have this string and I want to get only a distinct image filename.

```
/mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&amp;gtxResourceFileName=mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&amp
```

I have this regex code but it does not seem to work.

```
[^\/]*?_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4}\&
```

My expected output is:

```
mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png
```

But the actual output is:

```
mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&amp;gtxResourceFileName=mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using here?  The answer I imagine involves more than pure regex.

Comment: I'm using the https://regexr.com/

Comment: Try `[^&\/]*_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w+`, see https://regex101.com/r/TSp8XD/1

Comment: After validation through that tool. I do apply it in python regex.

Answer (score 2):

To find the unique filename in a string, you can use this regex,

```
([^\/&= ]+_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4})(?!.*\1)
```

Here, `([^\/&= ]+_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4})` captures the filename you require and `(?!.*\1)` negative look ahead gives you the last match ensuring the removal of all duplicates matches in the string. Also, because of appropriate negated character set, it allows matching Chinese character set too that are present in your filename which also you wanted to capture.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50lWef/5)**

Comment: It did not work with this string.

 , helvetica , sans-serif;\"><span style=\"font-size: 16.0px;\"><img alt=\"\" height=\"292\" src=\"ESLDesktop.Main?gtxResource=\/asset\/images\/一禅小和尚_Time1541635320463.jpg&amp;gtxResourceFileName=一禅小和尚.jpg&amp;mode=download\" width=\"292\" \/><\/span><\/span><\/p>"/mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&amp;gtxResourceFileName=mPastedImg_Time1469244713469.png&amp

Comment: The result should be capable of producing one or more distinct image filename.

Comment: @ReymartBetana: Didn't knew about this requirement. For that, you will have to select appropriate character set so it only gives you the intended match. In your input I see Chinese characters too, do you want a match for that as well? I guess yes.

Comment: It works now with your suggestion. Thanks a lot :)

[^\/&]+_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4}(?=&)

Comment: Yes I want also to match chineese chararcters. It's working now as expected.

Comment: @ReymartBetana: Actually a robust solution to give you unique matching file name is using this regex `([^\/&= ]+_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4})(?!.*\1)` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/50lWef/5/) and this matches Chinese filename as well. But its good you yourself tweaked and made the regex working for your requirement. Use the one that best suits your requirements. Glad to help and let me know if it doesn't work in any scenario.

Comment: Hey @ReymartBetana: Also please consider accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped solve your problem. That will also give you +2 reputation and benefit other users in case they come and reach your post looking for a solution similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has 2 matches where the second part has a larger match due to the negated character class `[^\/]` that matches not a forward slash.

What you might do is make the first character class more restrictive to specify what you would allow to match (for example `[a-zA-Z]`) and make sure that you don't use a global match to match all, but just one match:

```
[a-zA-Z]*_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5IP6G/1)

Note that you don't have to match the ampersand at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were quite close matching it, but you were doing too complex:

If you know that the name will be `mPastedImg_Time` then use it to the fullest.

What about simply doing it like this:

`mPastedImg_Time[0-9]{13}\.\w{3,4}`